# Joining Entities on query in Doctrine 2

Tags: php, join, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I am trying to join two entities in one advanced query in Doctrine 2. I am working with Zend Framework 2.

Unfortunately I have a hard time to find heads and tails in what I'm doing right now.

Here is what I have got in ZF2:

- I have build a module that is called `KryuuCategorizer`, that I am going to use for categorize all kinds of contents on the site.
- It is attached to a event called categorize, which will get a entity type

Categorizer has 2 Entities:

```
Category
  var id
  var name
  var objects

Object
  var id
  var entityName
  var module
  var entityId
  var category
```

`Category->objects` is bound by ManyToOne to `Object->category`

Then I need to bind the entity manually to the Object->entityId, I think I should be able to do this by using join in Doctrine 2.
But I am not sure where to start or how to get a grip on it.
I hope somebody can get me started and show me in the right direction, I looked at the Doctrine documentation, but got more confused than I should.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve what you want.

**1.** Add a `fetch="EAGER` to the relation definition

To do this add a `fetch="EAGER"` to the entity definition in your `Object`.

```
/** MANY-TO-ONE, OWNING SIDE
 * @var Category
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\Category", inversedBy="objects", fetch="EAGER")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 */
protected $category;
```

Eager loading is mentioned in the documentation [here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-eager-loading) and [here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#manytoone).

---

**2.** Write a custom DQL query in your `Object` repository and do a fetch join:

```
/**
 * Find object using DQL with a category joined.
 *
 * @param int $id
 * @return Building|null
 */
public function findObject($id)
{
    $entityManager = $this->getEntityManager();
    $query = $entityManager->createQuery(
        "SELECT o, c FROM Object o JOIN o.category c WHERE o.id = :id"
    );
    $query->setParameter('id', $id);
    $query->getOneOrNullResult();
}
```

These kind of joins are explained in the documentation [here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#joins). Watch the difference between fetch-join and regular joins.

---

**3.** Or use Doctrine `QueryBuilder` in your `Object` repository to get the same result:

```
/**
 * Find object using query builder with a category joined.
 *
 * @param int $id
 * @return Building|null
 */
public function findObject($id)
{
    $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('o')
        ->addSelect('c')
        ->leftJoin('o.category', 'c')
    }
    return = $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();
}
```

Be aware that If you want to fetch-join you also need to add the `addSelect` condition to the query, otherwise it is a regular join.

Comment: @KatsuoRyuu Did this answer your question?

Comment: Sorry for the long wait, Yes it did perfectly!